# Display just the first x value and change the scatter colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

In below code I'm attempting to change the colour of the scatter points to blue and limit
the number of 'x' entries to 1 using `xlim=c(0,1)` &  `color='blue'`

Here is the code :

```
xx = c('test1' , 'test2' , 'test3') 
yy = c(6 , 7 , 8) 
df <- data.frame(xx , yy)
ggplot(df, xlim=c(0,1) , aes(x=xx, y=yy , color='blue')) + geom_point(alpha = 1) + theme_bw()
```

This is not occurring :

[image]

How can limit the 'x' length of the graph and update the colour of the scatter points
to blue ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set color for all points then place `color="blue"` outside `aes()` in `geom_point()`.
To limit x axis only to `test1` values you can use `scale_x_discrtete()` and set `limits=` or subset your original data frame for this value.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=xx, y=yy)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1,color='blue') + theme_bw()+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("test1"))
```